# Django. Check in template or use an extra field?

Tags: python, django

I have some text fields in my Django model that are filled by a script, with values in English (the list of values is known).

But the app is actually made for Russian clients only. I'd like to translate those fields into Russian, and here comes a little question. These values are taken from an API response, which means I should check the value to translate it. What's faster: to check and translate fields in template or to make extra fields and translate strings in the Python script?

Comment: Template will be slower compared to script. Storing it up ahead should be better.

Comment: @AnuranjitMaindola thanks man. Btw, why do you think so? I'd be grateful if you attached a proof, but I bet that's not really necessary. Make it an answer so that I could mark it.

Comment: django has a built-in internalization you can use that

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada no, that's a bad way, 'cause values can be very.... specific for Russian language

Comment: @Ryan Snow,Can you show a minimum code example.

Comment: @RyanSnow, In internalization, you are still going to be the one who will define the translation from russian to english

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada oh, I misunderstood you then. I'll try it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is overhead of compiling Templates when rendering. So the more complicated the template gets (method calls etc), the performance tends to get slow (like py files are converted to pyc). Django has template caching but that also is limited (I don't know how much). I have faced performance issue because of lot of logic in templates. **Plus its always good to have a dumb client (template)**. I will prefer the Python approach because of the idea to keep **client thin** and not because of the performance gap.  Plus if tomorrow you need to add one more language then changing templates is always going to be difficult  then server.